# how to use selectionListener="#{bindings.Products.collectionModel. makeCurrent}" programmatically?

Tags: weblogic, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

i am using custom selection listener in a adf table component.so how can i invoke `selectionListener="#{bindings.Products.collectionModel. makeCurrent}"` programmatically to get selected rows/keys?

Answer (score 1):

Look at sample #23 at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/index-101235.html#CodeCornerSamples which shows how to do this in a generic way.

Answer (score 1):

... in addition you can use a MethodExpression to invoke the EL from Java. In this case your selection listener will initially create

- FacesContext instance
- ELContext
- ExpressionFactory
- MethodExpression (build from ExpressionFactory, the EL you put into your question will go in there)

... then you invoke the MethodExpression to execute the logic. The benefit you get out of such an approach is that you can perform pre- and post- processing (like pre- and post- triggers